# why treafik https config not work in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I am trying to configure https with traefik(v2.1.6) in kubernetes cluster(v1.15.2) by following this [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/https/acme/#caserver).

My traefik deployment `YAML` looks like this:

[image]

And this is my `IngressRoute` config:

```yaml
    apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
    kind: IngressRoute
    metadata:
      name: traefik-dashboard-route
      namespace: kube-system
    spec:
      entryPoints:
        - websecure
      tls:
        certresolver: ali
      routes:
        - match: Host(`traefik.example.com`) 
          kind: Rule
          services:
            - name: traefik
              port: 8080
```

When I access the website, it gives me following message: not secure.

What should I do to make it work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this certificate is from acme staging its root ca not present in browsers. You need to add it to your systems trust store.